# Series of Interview scheduling algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I am an HR and have to schedule interview of candidate with 5 interviewers one by one. I have calendar access of the 5 interviewers.
What algorithm can i use to schedule the one day optimized interview of candidate taking minimal breaks and interviews can be in any order.

Answer (score 1):

1) Determine how long each interview takes. Divide the time in a day by the worst case to determine how many "interview slots" there are per day. *Note: If you use "average time an interview takes" in the hope of cramming more interviews into each day then you risk causing delays everywhere when an interview takes longer than average.*

2) Give "interview slots" a number from 0 to N.

3) Assign "interview slots" to interviewers such that:

- the first interviewer has them in numerical order (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
- the second interviewer has them in "XOR 1" order (1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6)
- the third interviewer has them in "XOR 2" order (2, 3, 0, 1, 6, 7, 4, 5)
- the fourth interviewer has them in "XOR 3" order (3, 2, 1, 0, 7, 6, 5, 4)
- the fifth interviewer has them in "XOR 4" order (4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3)

4) Assign candidates to "interview slots" in ascending order. E.g. the first candidate gets "interview slot 0" so they see first interviewer, then second, then third, then fourth, then fifth interviewer; the second candidate gets "interview slot 1" so they see second interviewer, then first, then fourth, then third, then have to wait, then see fifth interviewer.